# How to select from a table and RIGHT JOIN it with a LIST in MySQL

Tags: mysql, list, join

I am hoping to do something like:

```
SELECT client.id FROM client RIGHT JOIN ('no@such.com', 'a@b.com', ...);
```

I have the following "client" table:

```
id   email
1    a@b.com
2    c@d.com
```

The user inputs a list of email addresses that he wants to invite, and I need to get the following result:

```
email_to_invite  client.id
no@such.com      NULL
a@b.com          1
```

so that I know who is already in the DB (and get's a message with the internal message system), and who I need to invite by email (client.id IS NULL)

**SOLUTION:** (Thanks to Joe Stefanelli)

First I had to grant CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES permission to my user

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE email (email VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO email VALUES ('no@such.com'), ('a@b.com');
SELECT e.email, c.id FROM email e LEFT JOIN client c ON e.email=c.email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the user list into a temporary table and join against that.

Answer (score 0):

In order fo find the clients that are not on the email list you can do the following:

```
SELECT client.id FROM client WHERE email NOT IN ('no@such.com', 'a@b.com')
```

Comment: -1 this would give me all the clients in the table that I didn't invite

Answer (score 0):

You could assume that these people might join, so create client records for them if they don't exist.

Assuming you have a Boolean field that says whether a client is a member and you have a unique key on the email address column, you could insert like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO client (email, is_member) VALUES ('no@such.com', false);
INSERT IGNORE INTO client (email, is_member) VALUES ('a@b.com', false);
```

Then, to get your invites, it's simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM client
WHERE is_member = false
  AND email IN ('no@such.com', 'a@b.com')
```

You could extend this to avoid sending multiple invites, or limit the number of invites. If it's a social site, you could also build relationships between clients and non-members, so you could recommend connections once someone signs up. My point is that there are advantages to storing the email addresses for non-members for these kinds of tasks.